# error: storage size of ‘array’ isn’t constant

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that replaces every tab input into 4 spaces (This is a program said in the K&R 2 book).
When I try to compile the program it says "`error: storage size of 'eline' isn't constant`".
What does that mean and how to fix it?

Note: I removed the `main()` function since it doesn't cause any errors

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define TAB 4

void etab(char line[]){
        int c, i, j, l;
        j = i = l = 0;
        while ((c=getchar())!=EOF && j < MAXLINE){
                ++j;
                if (c == '\t'){
                        ++i;
                }
                line[j] = c;
                if (c == '\n'){
                        break;
                }
        }
        ++j;
        line[j] = '\0';

        int len = MAXLINE+(i*TAB);

        extern char eline[len];

        j = i = 0;

        while (line[j]!='\0'){
                if (l == 1){
                        for (i=0;i<TAB+1;++i){
                                eline[j+i] = ' ';
                        }
                }

                if (line[j] == '\t'){
                        l = 1;
                }else{
                        line[j] = eline[j];
                }
                ++j;
        }
}

'''
```

Comment: Global arrays can't have a variable size.

Comment: Where is `eline` defined?  Please update your post with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`extern char eline[len];` declares `eline` to be an array with static storage duration. C 2018 6.7.6.2 2 says:

> … If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

In other words, the C standard does not support this. The array length must be fixed at compile time; it cannot be a run-time value.

If you do not need `eline` to be visible outside this function, you can remove `extern` and use just `char eline[len];`. That will declare it with automatic storage duration, for which a variable length is allowed.

However, then you cannot return `eline` from the function. If you need to provide a new array to the caller, you will have to use dynamic memory allocation or other techniques.

Comment: when I try to delete len it gives me: ```/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccORMAFR.o: in function `etab':
etab.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `eline'
/usr/bin/ld: etab.c:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `eline'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically allocate Memory with `malloc()` function.
I suggest you write this like of code as `extern char* eline = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len)` this should allocate Memory and create an array (remember to use `free(eline)` at the end) hope this helps.

Comment: when I implement this, it gives me this extern char* eline = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len) and error: initializer element is not constant

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to declare an array whose size in memory is not known at compile time. I suggest you read about static and dynamic memory allocation in C.